# Docker Container to Host Routing

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I need a better up-to-date solution the following problem:

Problem: I have to manually create an iptable rule in order to allow a route from a dynamically docker bridge to the host. Otherwise container a cannot connect to container b because there is by default no route from a docker network to the docker host itself.

I have the following setup:

```
container-nginx (docker)
|
|-container-jira (docker) (https://jira.example.com)
|-container-confluence (docker) (https://confluence.example.com)
```

In order to have properly functioning Atlassian application links between Jira and Confluence:

- Jira accesses Confluence over https://confluence.example.com
- Confluence accesses Jira over https://jira.example.com

I use docker-compose for the whole setup and all container are inside the same network. By default this will not work i will get "no route to host" in both containers for hosts confluence.example.com and jira.example.com. Because every container inside the docker network have no route to the docker host itself.

Currently, each time the setup is initialized I manually create an iptable rule from the dynamically created docker bridge with id "br-wejfiweji" to the host.

This is cumbersome, is there "a new way" or "better way" to do this in Docker 1.11.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose version 2 does create a network which allows all containers to see each other. See "[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)" (since docker 1.10)

If your containers are created with the right hostname, that is `jira.example.com` and `confluence.example.com` (see [`docker-compose.yml` hostname directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cpu-shares-cpu-quota-cpuset-domainname-hostname-ipc-mac-address-mem-limit-memswap-limit-privileged-read-only-restart-shm-size-stdin-open-tty-user-working-dir)), nginx can proxy-pass directly to `jira.example.com` and `confluence.example.com`.
Those two hostname will resolve to the right IP address within the network created by docker-compose for those 3 (nginx, jira and confluence) containers.

I suggest in the comment to use an **[alias](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks)** in order for jira to see confluence as nginx (nginx being aliases to confluence), in order for jira to always use nginx when accessing confluence.

```
version: '2'

services:
  # HTTPS-ReverseProxy
  nginx:
    image: blacklabelops/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - 'crucible.example.com'
          - 'confluence.example.com'
          - 'crowd.example.com'
          - 'bitbucket.example.com'
          - 'jira.example.com'
    ports:
      - '443:443'
```

Comment: I am already using docker-compose 2. In my case the route must be jira -> nginx (https) -> confluence. How can I attach multiple hostname (e.g. jira.example.com, confluence.example.com) to my one nginx container?

Comment: @maybeg version2 mean all containers see each other: jira sees nginx and confluence. Try and `docker exec <jira_id> bash`, and see if you can ping the other two containers.

Comment: I need to route over nginx because each instance is adressing the other instance by its https protocoll. The application link is used by atlassian products to generate links inside the ui. The http link will work between the instances and yes they will ping and see each other but the generated http link inside the ui will not work inside the browser.

Comment: @maybeg then you could try and modify your /etc/hosts of jira with confluence being an alias for nginx/confluence (and nginx proxy-passing to confluence)

Comment: Hard to do with the default bridge network where ip may change for each container restart. Any recommendation for a network driver?

Comment: @maybeg with the new docker networking, you could declare nginx with a 'confluence' alias attached to it (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks), that way jira would actually contact nginx when trying to access confluence.

Comment: Sounds awesome! I will try it!

Comment: Works! Needs at least docker-compose 1.6.1. Also nginx internal port must match the exposed external port.

Comment: @maybeg Great! Could you edit this answer with the docker-compose.yml that you ended up using?